# What is double curly braces inside dict used for in python?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, jinja2, airflow

I have a python dict, which is a config to a job which looks like this:

```
#Values
varX = "x"
varY = "y"

conf={
        "spark.someVal": '{{ someComplexMethod("test") }}'
    }
```

Problem is that when I want to replace/modify the returned value from the method with some globally declared values, it does not reflect since it is probably not in scope.

for eg, This works:

```
conf={
        "spark.someVal": '{{ someComplexMethod("test").replace("x","y") }}'
    }
```

But below lines don't.

```
conf={
        "spark.someVal": '{{ someComplexMethod("test").replace(varX, varY) }}'
    }

OR

conf={
        "spark.someVal": '{{ someComplexMethod("test") }}'.replace(varX, varY)
    }
```

I don't want to use values directly, any way around this? And can someone please explain what is the use of curly braces here.

Comment: You have a dictionnary with the keys as string and the values as string. Not sure what you mean here, the curly braces are inside the string.. so it's just a string.

Comment: uhh.. probably this is something spark or jinja related, might want to update the tags accordingly in that case.

Comment: Looks like it's something expected by some library that's being used, it's not like a standard Python thing if that's what you're asking

Comment: [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) is a *templating* framework where you can write code like you have with the intention of executing/subsituting the fields within the double braces at a later point, or perhaps repeatedly as part of a job. because the intention is not that the templates be populated at the execution time of the python script you're running, it's super important to know the context in which the strings will be evaluated. so we can't really help with this - you'll probably need to go to someone you work/collaborate with who you could ask about how this is run.

Comment: since you mention airflow - yep - you can use jinja templates to create airflow jobs. their [docs on templating](//airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja) "barely scratch the surface" (their words, but I agree), but you can see how templating can be used to create large DAGs. Think of this as a language for writing python scripts which will be executed elsewhere. The full [airflow templates reference docs](//airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#templates-ref) provide a list of variables available within template strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can setup `varX` and `varY` as [Airflow Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/variables.html).

Then you can use them in your Jinja templates like so:

```
'{{ someComplexMethod("test").replace(var.value.varX, var.value.varY) }}'
```

Comment: This worked, had to add the vars through airflow admin console first though.